# Random box in UITableView when building for iOS 5?

Tags: uitableview, ios5

I have a weird box showing up when building for iOS 5. I am making one of my apps compatible for iOS 5 (originally built for iOS 4) so I got the new XCode and built it and it looks like this. Any idea what it is? It scrolls with the UITableView, but when it reaches the top it stops and you can see content through it. Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Coulton

[image: here it is]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a section header. Make sure you don't implement one of these methods in your delegate/data source:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Apple changed the behavior of section headers in iOS 5. In past versions, section headers were not shown if these methods returned nil. Starting with iOS 5, returning nil isn't enough. You either don't implement these methods, or set the header height to 0 (either using `tableView.sectionHeaderHeight` or by implementing `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`).

Comment: You are my hero. I checked my `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` and it I had the section height 50. Changed it to 0 and works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you don't use headers at all, just remove the implementations for these methods (titleForHeaderInSection, viewForHeaderInSection, heightForHeaderInSection); it's better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you don't have an empty view in the header of the UITableView your XIB file.